# Jquery datatable when checkbox is checked, all the rows should be transfered to new jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have two datatable the first datatable when checkbox is checked the rows are transferred to a new jquery datatable. I also I have a chk all checkbox when the checkbox is checked I want all the table rows to be transfered to the other datatable.

Here are the two tables

```
var primaryTable = $('#tblProveedorToTransfert').DataTable({
            //code that generates datatable 
     });

var secondTable = $('#tblProveedorTransferd').DataTable({ 
     //code that generates datatable 
});
```

This is the code that should transfer all the rows to the other table. However only the rows that are visually visible are transferred and not all the rows on all the pages.

```
        $('#chkAll').click(function (e) {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
            $('#tblProveedorToTransfert tbody').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                var alereadyAdded = false;

            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                for (var i = rowsIDs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (rowsIDs[i] === $(this).attr("data-id"))
                    {
                        alereadyAdded = true;
                    }
                }
                if (alereadyAdded === false)
                {
                    rowsIDs.push($(this).attr("data-id"));
                }
            }
            else {
                for (var i = rowsIDs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (rowsIDs[i] === $(this).attr("data-id")) {
                        rowsIDs.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            secondTable.ajax.reload();
            });

    });
```

What must I modify in my code to transfer all the rows and not just the visible ones. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Define transfer....copy to other table or remove all data and put it all in the other table.

Comment: Irregardless your approach needs to be to work with data cached in each instance not the rendered html

Comment: @charlietfl transferred: copy rows to other table. How can I use  data cached in each instance like you are suggesting.

Comment: The plugin api has method to get all the data and methods to add row(s). Will probably need some array filtering also to prevent duplicates. What you are asking is not trivial but is quite doable. Will require breaking this down into small steps and working on each step and researching the various methods in the plugin docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make another column in data source for your table, to storing the checkbox status (for eg: requestTransfer)
2. attach event onclicked with every checkbox, whenever the checkbox status changed, update the new added column/field from the step 1.
3. When rendering the checkbox, load the value of that field, and render the checkbox status
4. When do copying, check the new added column to see if the row is needed to copy or not.